# Passing unique variables into a Ruby Thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, variables

I am creating threads in a `for` loop, and I want to use the `for` loop's `i` as the name for each particular thread. When I run this, instead of getting `1`,`2` or `2`,`1`, I am getting `2`,`2`. Is there a better/safer way to pass variables into a thread?

```
ts = []
for i in 1..2 do
  ts.push( Thread.new(i) do
    x = i
    puts x
  end)
end
ts.each do |t|
  t.join()
end
```

Comment: Don't forget the `i` in the main `for` loop is shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variable through the block

```
ts = []

for i in 1..2 do
  ts.push( Thread.new(i) do |i|
    x = i
    puts x
  end)
end

ts.each do |t|
  t.join()
end

# => 1
# => 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `i` you are referring to is not a block variable passed to the thread but is the `i` defined outside of the thread. You need to add `|i|` to it, and you will get either `1`, `2` or `2`, `1`.

```
ts = []
for i in 1..2 do
  ts.push( Thread.new(i) do |i|
    x = i
    puts x
  end)
end
ts.each do |t|
  t.join()
end
```

By the way, a more rubyish way to write is:

```
ts = (1..2).map do |i|
  Thread.new(i) do |i|
    puts i
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

If you are looking for a unique name for each thread, I suggest using the object id of the thread.

```
ts = (1..2).map do
  Thread.new do
    puts Thread.current.object_id
  end
end.each(&:join)
```